# WebRequestMethods.Ftp to navigate to directory

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to upload a file via ftp using FtpWebRequest as below:

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp.somethong.com");

ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
```

However, when connected and uploaded the file goes into the root, whereas, I need for it to be put into the /Upload directory.

I can make directories but how can I browse there, before uploading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put the directory in the URL you used to create the request, i.e.

```
 ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.somethong.com/Upload/filename.ext");
```

Comment: When trying your suggestion:
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp.adftest.rightmove.com/test/upload/test.zip");
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

And then when trying:
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://adftest.rightmove.com/test/upload/test.zip");
Unable to connect to remote server

Comment: ^^ not to clear. Essentially, with your suggestion I get Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. When trying .Create("ftp://adftest.rightmove.com/test/upload/test.zip"); I get Unable to connect to remote server.

Comment: Right, sorry, the URI needs a scheme (ftp://).

Comment: As above I get unable to connect to remote server, maybe some permissions on the ftp server but the method should work. In the end I used: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftplib.aspx